# App crashing with Picasso and minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, proguard, release

```
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:there were 52 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
Job failed, see logs for details
```

This is the error I was getting when trying to build my release.apk.

I tried to fix it by adding:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
```

in my `pro guard-rules.pro` file.

The release.apk now builds correctly, at least apparently it does.

**But when I install the app on my phone (or any phone), it crashes at launch, I think when it starts loading the images with Picasso.**

Please help me fix this problem.

I have tried some solutions found on the internet and suggested from you, they all seem to build correctly, but the app still keeps crashing. Could it depend on something else other than pro guard rules?

This is how my gradle looks like:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-picasso.pro

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, I tried this one too, no luck either :(

Comment: That should at least fix picasso, not any other libraries

Comment: @cricket_007 there are no other libraries trowing any warnings. Plus the code has got to be fine, since it's working when the apk is built in debug mode

Comment: Try these? https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-okhttp.pro

Comment: @cricket_007 no luck either

Comment: Your included ProGuard rule files are redundant. Either remove the first line that says `proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'` or remove `, 'proguard-rules.pro'` from the second line and change `proguardFiles` to the singular `proguardFile`. Finally, as others have said, while you don’t need `-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**` in the rules, `-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**` would have been the solution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You seem to be minifying OkHTTP still

`can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp`

Head over to [Picasso's Github page](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/README.md)

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. I tried to use this one too, without any luck. It does actually fix it, since the apk is generated normally. Still when I install the app, it crashes at launch as soon as it has to load the images using Picasso

Comment: Can you filter the logcat for errors and not warnings?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec

Comment: I can't this warnings are showing up in messages. this is the only error I'm getting `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details`

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the correct proguard file in Gradle?

Comment: This actually fixed the Picasso error. The app crashing was because `SearchView` couldn't load. I added `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }` to my pro guard rules and the app is working perfectly.

Comment: This is not about “minifying OkHTTP” or not. That would be `-keep`. Here we have `-dontwarn`. The [docs](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) say: “Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. […] Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code will not function properly.” But as per [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader/issues/23), the warnings are indeed safe to ignore.

Comment: Using below rules. :- -keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
#.       But it didn't help

Answer (score 13):

try these to your proguard.cfg:

```
#### -- Picasso --
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

 #### -- OkHttp --

 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.**

 #### -- Apache Commons --

 -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try this out

Comment: I think you want `keep` not `dontwarn`

Comment: Nothing, it builds correctly, but keeps crashing at launch

Comment: @cricket_007 what should I `keep`?

Comment: @Daniele all this answer does is silence the warnings. It doesn't fix a class not being resolved

Comment: @cricket_007 I see this is probably why it still keeps crashing after I build it. Have you got any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: are you sure image link is working? i have face this problem once because image links wasn't working

Comment: try clean and rebuilt

Comment: are you sure that app is Crashing because of Picasso only there may be another lib which is creating problems in Release version.

Answer (score 2):

Solved adding this line in `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your app gradle

minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false

Comment: this idea is not good, you are trying to disable Proguard

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that I could not generate a signed apk with `minifyEnabled true` and I have fixed it by adding the following to the `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
#for Picasso library
-dontwarn okio.
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

or you can use the following if the above still causes problems:

```
#for Picasso library
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.* { *;}
-dontwarn okio.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
```